# Graphing a process's memory usage

Tags: memory, ubuntu, process, monitoring, metrics

Does anyone know of a tool to visually show the memory usage of a selected process on Ubuntu?

`ps aux` will show a numerical snapshot, but I'd really like a line I can watch change as I hammer the process and hopefully see unexpected behaviours.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I couldn't find any real tools to do it.

But I have found a neat small set of scripts that'll do it.

Using this little bash loop to do the logging:

```
while true; do
ps -C <ProgramName> -o pid=,%mem=,vsz= >> /tmp/mem.log
gnuplot /tmp/show_mem.plt
sleep 1
done &
```

This will create a nice little log file of memory usage called /tmp/mem.log. Then it generates an image of the data with gnuplot using the following script (put this in `/tmp/show_mem.plt`):

```
set term png small size 800,600
set output "mem-graph.png"

set ylabel "VSZ"
set y2label "%MEM"

set ytics nomirror
set y2tics nomirror in

set yrange [0:*]
set y2range [0:*]

plot "/tmp/mem.log" using 3 with lines axes x1y1 title "VSZ", \
     "/tmp/mem.log" using 2 with lines axes x1y2 title "%MEM"
```

Then opening the image with the default GNOME image viewer it keeps reloading the image when it changes. So if all the above loop is backgrounded it will appear that you have an amazing memory usage graphing tool running within an image viewer :)

The process I'm tracking right now looks like this:
[image: Graph of rising memory usage]

It looks like I do have some memory issues :(

Much of this was ripped from http://brunogirin.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/memory-usage-graphs-with-ps-and-gnuplot.html, credit where it is due.

Comment: I love your contribution man! Just a word of advise, in my machine 1s delay was too soon and cpu usage spiked to about 50%, changed it to 5s which was still good enough for me and all is great :)

Comment: I have improved it a little bit to make it completely automated. My version is https://gist.github.com/nicolasazrak/32d68ed6c845a095f75f037ecc2f0436

Answer (score 28):

The accepted answer worked for me, but I was a bit tired of doing so much copy/pasting every time I want to measure memory, so I've created a small tool for this: https://github.com/parikls/mem_usage_ui

Install using

```
pip install mem_usage_ui
```

Start the browser GUI by typing `mem_usage_ui` in the shell.

This is what the result will look like:

[image]

Comment: `mem_usage_ui` was a pleasure to use. Thanks!

Comment: Great tool, it did the work in 20s :)

Comment: Answers should be more than a link, please include details on a) how to install, b) how to run, similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62876993/7483211

Answer (score 20):

Resident set size of the target, `$PID`, process can be streamed to [ttyplot](https://github.com/tenox7/ttyplot) for live display:

```
while :; do grep -oP '^VmRSS:\s+\K\d+' /proc/$PID/status \
    | numfmt --from-unit Ki --to-unit Mi; sleep 1; done | ttyplot -u Mi
```

[image: asciicast]

`ttyplot -u Mi` above can be replaced with `feedgnuplot --stream --line --point --xlen 20` to get more or less the same plot in GUI (of `gnuplot`, which, for instance, has image export). [feedgnuplot](https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot) should be [installable with `apt-get`](https://pkgs.org/download/feedgnuplot).

Comment: Good answer because answer for a live plot answer

Comment: Only answer that shows usage over time in a tty! Nice.

Comment: `while :; do grep -oP '^MemAvailable:\s+\K\d+' /proc/meminfo     | numfmt --from-unit Ki --to-unit Mi; sleep 1; done | ttyplot -u Mi` to plot all available system memory instead

Comment: And how do I get the PID number of a process before I start it? Would I use the PID of the shell that I'm running?
This isn't an end-to-end answer unfortunately for this reason.

Comment: E.g. try `pgrep`. Replace `$PID` with `$(pgrep --newest PROGRAM)`.

Answer (score 12):

Python package [Memory Profiler](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler) works with non-Python executable binaries too.

Use `mprof` to generate a full memory usage report of your executable and to plot it:

```sh
mprof run <executable>
mprof plot
```

The plot would be something like this:

[image: Performance plot]

It is available on PyPI, so it can be installed:

```sh
pip install -U memory_profiler
```

Comment: Memory Profiler's README led me to believe it was much more complicated so I ignored it and tried to roll my own using variations of the other answers. This is the missing quick start guide!

Comment: Now it **is** the quick start guide: https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/pull/358

Comment: Wow! I am happy that it was helpful!

Comment: In contrast to the two highest ranking answers, this works out of the box. Very simple.

Answer (score 9):

I really like using "htop" instead of "top". It's very colorful and has a lot of options like setup, search, invert, tree, sort by, nice, kill. Give it a try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install htop
```

[image: htop]

Comment: Cheers César, however I was hoping for a GUI interface... some pretty lines going up and down on a time v memory axis.  I don't really want to have to write something to pull data out and graph it myself.  Any ideas about that bit?

Comment: Most spreadsheet programs can import data in columns and then graph it.

Comment: While I'm a big fan of htop, it's much better at displaying instantaneous memory usage rather than memory usage over time.

Comment: htop has a graph mode to display memory/CPU usage over time: https://hisham.hm/htop/index.php?page=screenshots

Answer (score 3):

Top will do the trick

```
top -b | grep {name of process}
top -b -p {PID}
top -b -u {userid}
```

Comment: Cheers, considered 'top', but i'm looking for a graphical representation.

Answer (score -4):

Try running the command "top" in the command line. This will display a list of processes similar to the windows task manager.